# Get all elements in listview visible/invisible

Tags: android, listview, appium, listadapter

I'm trying to get all the data from the listview and I know that it is impossible with appium because you only get the visible ones.

Now, I've read something about the adapters data?
But is it possible to get those data in some way without Appium?

Kind regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: before creating listview you have arraylist that contain all data. You can use that.

Comment: And how do I access this one?

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: he wants to access the "arraylist" you mentioned(that contains all data of list view) in your comment through appium code and iterate over all the data for the purpose of automating a test scenario.